# Merge multiple rows into 1 replacing nulls

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My source df has multiple rows with same values across multiple columns like `(cartId|orderid|anchor_item|dt)` but with nulls across multiple columns like`(impressions_sub_item_1|impressions_sub_item_2|impressions_sub_item_3|impressions_sub_item_4|impressions_sub_item_5|click_sub_item_1|click_sub_item_2|click_sub_item_3|click_sub_item_4|click_sub_item_5)`

How to merge the rows so that I have a distinct row grouped on `(cartId|orderid|anchor_item|dt)` along with max date

```
+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|              cartId|orderid|anchor_item|      dt|           ts|impressions_sub_item_1|impressions_sub_item_2|impressions_sub_item_3|impressions_sub_item_4|impressions_sub_item_5|click_sub_item_1|click_sub_item_2|click_sub_item_3|click_sub_item_4|click_sub_item_5|
+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|  401748900|20230425|1682458222928|            1633440001|            1578012998|             294547044|            1651451907|            1515684306|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|  154954681|20230425|1682458287621|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|            null|            null|            null|            null|        22309200|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|  154954681|20230425|1682458273853|              55153649|              13448877|             136701169|             451827274|              22309200|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|   44391182|20230425|1682458246406|             889729524|              44391067|              49932940|             156935696|             190577310|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|   16004756|20230425|1682458310240|             611081668|              47076387|                  null|                  null|                  null|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|   10535232|20230425|1682458294812|              10307473|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|   44390974|20230425|1682458340704|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|            null|            null|       199507043|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|   44390974|20230425|1682458320872|             481388369|             159106613|             199507043|              44391113|              14151382|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|  222136101|20230425|1682458209088|             547386449|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Expected DF

```
+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|              cartId|orderid|anchor_item|      dt|impressions_sub_item_1|impressions_sub_item_2|impressions_sub_item_3|impressions_sub_item_4|impressions_sub_item_5|click_sub_item_1|click_sub_item_2|click_sub_item_3|click_sub_item_4|click_sub_item_5|
+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|  222136101|20230425|             547386449|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|   44391182|20230425|             889729524|              44391067|              49932940|             156935696|             190577310|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|   10535232|20230425|              10307473|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|  401748900|20230425|            1633440001|            1578012998|             294547044|            1651451907|            1515684306|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|   44390974|20230425|             481388369|             159106613|             199507043|              44391113|              14151382|            null|            null|       199507043|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|   16004756|20230425|             611081668|              47076387|                  null|                  null|                  null|            null|            null|            null|            null|            null|
|e4fde174-4ded-4da   |      #|  154954681|20230425|              55153649|              13448877|             136701169|             451827274|              22309200|            null|            null|            null|            null|        22309200|
+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

How can I do this in the best efficient way?

---

```
Solution: 

from functools import reduce
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dfs = reduce(
    lambda x, y: x.withColumn(y, f.explode_outer(y)),
    c.columns[9:], 
    c.groupBy(c.columns[:8],).agg(*[f.collect_list(c).alias(c) for c in c.columns[9:]])
).distinct()

The above code addresses my question, but i also need the max ts for the group records as a column
```

Comment: The question need more details, what id column you are using, your show is not showing completely (...), also what column you need to replace exactly and with what ?

Comment: From initial check your expected output is only filtering NULL from the column `impressions1` if that's what you expect you can achieve this using a simple filter with column not null.

If that's not what you expect you would need to expand a bit more on your question as its really too vague to understand the requirement